# how to remove html tags after display xml content in php?

Tags: php, xml, strip-tags

how to remove html tags after display xml content in php? i have also tried `strip_tags` but is not working to remove the html tags ?

**php code**

```
<?php

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->load( 'aboutus.xml' );

 $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
 foreach( $items as $item )
 {

 $contents = $item->getElementsByTagName( "content" );
 $content = $contents->item(0)->nodeValue;
 $a= $content;
 }
 ?>
```

**display xml content in php page**

```
 <div style="width:50%" align="center"> <?php echo strip_tags($a) ?></div>
```

**aboutus.xml file **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item><pubDate>Sat, 05 Oct 2013 14:43:39 +0500</pubDate>

<title><![CDATA[Who We Are]]></title>

<url><![CDATA[about-us]]></url>

<meta><![CDATA[]]></meta>

<metad><![CDATA[]]></metad>

<menu><![CDATA[About Us]]></menu>

<menuOrder><![CDATA[0]]></menuOrder>

<menuStatus><![CDATA[]]></menuStatus>

<template><![CDATA[template.php]]></template>

<parent><![CDATA[]]></parent>

<content>
<![CDATA[&lt;h1&gt;Who We Are&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;About Desk&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=\&quot;text-align: justify;\&quot;&gt;
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\&#039;s standard dummy text ever since 
the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled 
it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
]]>
</content>

</item>
```

**display content screenshot**

[image]

**solution**

```
<?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($a)) ?>
```

Comment: Your code should work, see: https://eval.in/96248 The `&nbsp;` is double encoded, so that might need an additional str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are seeing is not actually HTML. The `<` and `>` characters are being changed to entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`. You can change them back with `html_entity_decode()`.

You could then use `strip_tags()` to remove the HTML or you could retain it as it would now work as HTML should.

So, for example, you could change `<?php echo strip_tags($a) ?>` in your own code to `<?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($a)) ?>`

Comment: can you explain your answer?

Comment: @voodoo417 What do you feel needs to be explained more?

Comment: Reading the nodeValue will return the decoded entities. No need for additional decoding.

Comment: @DampeS8N "first version" of your answer had not any sense.